# Reliable backup system with Ubuntu and ISP Config

Tags: backup, aws

I'm setting up new servers and I finally have a functional Ubuntu Web Server on EC2 Amazon AWS with:

- ISPConfig
- MySQL
- Postfix
- Bind
- Amavisd-New
- OpenDKIM

Some domains are in Route 53 DNS Zone and others in GoDaddy.

How can I create a reliable automatic backup system, mirror servers or whatever that you can recommend me? I need a method or system where I can restore past partial backups, a domain, a database, a folder, etc.

It will be great if you can tell me more about "high availability" servers too.

Thank you and best regards from Argentina!